# Strange output when trying to get data from Registry

Tags: powershell

I have a startup script that captures an IP address out of the registry using the following code:

```
$icaaddr=(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Citrix\XTEConfig" -Name "DefaultICAAddress")
[Net.IPAddress]$icaaddr=$icaaddr.DefaultICAAddress
```

Later in that script that IP is used for different things and it is added to the "Message" output as such

```
$message+="ICA address found to be: $icaaddr `n"
```

However today on one server instead of an IP the following was captured.

```
ICA address found to be: @{DefaultICAAddress=; PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Citrix\XTEConfig; PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Citrix; PSChildName=XTEConfig; PSDrive=HKLM; PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry}
```

So my questions are 2

1. What would cause such output
2. How could I test for this 'state'

Long story short is when the ouptut is like that I need to have the server rebooted.  How can I test the $icaaddr variable contains a valid IP address

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

`$icaaddr=(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Citrix\XTEConfig" -Name "DefaultICAAddress")`

to:

`$icaaddr=(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Citrix\XTEConfig" -Name "DefaultICAAddress").DefaultICAAddress`

or (this way is more readable IMO):

```
$icaaddr = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Citrix\XTEConfig" `
    -Name "DefaultICAAddress" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "DefaultICAAddress"
```

because Get-ItemProperty returns an object and you need a single property.

Note, however, that in your example `DefaultICAAddress` seems to be empty and trying to cast it to `[Net.IPAddress]` will likely throw an exception. To avoid this you should [check if the value is a valid IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address).

Comment: sorry for the delay but I don't think you understand my problem.  This script works fine as is.  Reboot hundreds of servers with it.  However on one server this one day I saw the above.  Rebooted the same server again and it worked fine.  Just trying to figure out what went wrong.