# regex for //Server Name or IP Address/Sharedfolder/Path/to/Saved/Files

Tags: php, regex, validation

I found this

```
^\/(\/[^\s\/]+)+(\/)?$
```

But it matches right after the double forward slashes and any character

I need it to match to at least *//servernameoripaddress/shareddir* and it can go on from there ie. *//Server Name or IP Address/Sharedfolder/Path/to/Saved/Files*

Thank you all, I would appreciate any help for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-dns-hostname-or-ip-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-dns-hostname-or-ip-address):

```
^//(?:(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])|(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))(?:/[^/]+)+$
```

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/vH5iH1/1)

Explanation:

```
^// # make sure the string starts with two slashes
(?: # match an IP address...
    (([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])
| #... or a host name
    (([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])
)
(?:
    /[^/]+ # match a slash, followed by at least one character...
)+ #... at least once
$ # and make sure the string ends here
```