# preg_match_all doesn't match all hostnames

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Ok, I'm trying to get hostnames and i'm using [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-dns-hostname-or-ip-address):

```
preg_match_all("/^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/", 'google.com some text example.com', $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Matches should be:

```
google.com
example.com
```

but, the output is the first match only (google.com)

What i should change to get all matches please?

Comment: The regular expression that you're using is to test whether a string is a hostname; it's not meant to match *all* possible hostnames it can find inside a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cheap trick you could apply is to simply replace your anchors with a word boundary assertion:

```
preg_match_all("/\b(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\b/", 'google.com some text example.com', $matches);
//               ^^                                                                                                         ^^
```

That would yield:

```
Array(
  [0] => google.com
  [1] => some
  [2] => text
  [3] => example.com
)
```

To filter out word without at least one period:

```
preg_match_all("/\b(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\b/", 'google.com some text example.com', $matches);
//                                                                       ^
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually return an empty array for me because you have start of line (^) and end of line ($) in your pattern. If you remove this you will get more results. But still not google.com and exaple.com because you RegExp is written that way that 1 letter is enough. That what I got

```
Array
(
    [0] => google.c
    [1] => o
    [2] => m
    [3] => s
    [4] => o
    [5] => m
    [6] => e
    [7] => t
    [8] => e
    [9] => x
    [10] => t
    [11] => example.c
    [12] => o
    [13] => m
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all("/[a-z]+[:.].*?(?=\s|$)/", 'google.com some text example.com', $matches);
```

See the result here: http://ideone.com/sBvrSl