# Python: ipaddress AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute

Tags: python, ip-address, ipv6, ipv4

Following the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994223/regex-for-range-of-ipv4-addresses), I'm using the check the `ipaddress` module to perform checks of type:

```
In [25]: IPv4Address(u'100.64.1.1') in IPv4Network(u'100.64.0.0/10')
Out[25]: True
```

Works fine in IPython. Yet when I turn it into a function:

```
import ipaddress
def isPrivateIp(ip):
    ip4addressBlocks = [u'0.0.0.0/8', u'10.0.0.0/8', u'100.64.0.0/10', u'127.0.0.0/8', u'169.254.0.0/16', u'172.16.0.0/12', u'192.0.0.0/24', u'192.0.2.0/24', u'192.88.99.0/24', 
    u'192.168.0.0/16', u'198.18.0.0/15', u'198.51.100.0/24', u'203.0.113.0/24', u'224.0.0.0/4', u'240.0.0.0/4', u'255.255.255.255/32']
    unicoded = unicode(ip)
    if any(unicoded in ipaddress.IPv4Network(address) for address in ip4addressBlocks):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print isPrivateIp(r'169.254.255.1')
```

I get:

```
  File "isPrivateIP.py", line 14, in <module>
    print isPrivateIp(r'169.254.255.1')
  File "isPrivateIP.py", line 9, in isPrivateIp
    if any(unicoded in ipaddress.IPv4Network(address) for address in ip4addressBlocks):
  File "isPrivateIP.py", line 9, in <genexpr>
    if any(unicoded in ipaddress.IPv4Network(address) for address in ip4addressBlocks):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaddress.py", line 705, in __contains__
    if self._version != other._version:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_version'
```

Why so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You check if the unicode string `ip` is in the network, whereas before you've used an `IPv4Address` instance.

Your test must instead be

```
if any(IPv4Address(unicoded) in ipaddress.IPv4Network(address) for address \
       in ip4addressBlocks):
```

Answer (score 3):

@Phillip's answer is correct, I just want to expand on it a bit. I think from your other questions you're crashing through a lot of programming and Python-specific ideas all at once, and some explanation might help - or at least demonstrate that it's dense code, but not *magic*, and give you some other terms to Google if you want to.

**Objects**

It's a big topic, and there is no easy tutorial introduction, so I'm not going to try and link one. But when you do `IPv4Address(u'100.64.1.1')`, it's not *just* testing whether the IP address is a valid address yes or no, it's taking a lot of code that deals with IP addresses, wrapping it around the address you gave, and returning *the whole thing*.

Like Tony Stark putting on his Iron Man suit, this takes basic text and gives you a suited-up IPv4Address *object* with loads of enhancements tuned for working with IP addresses.

`IPv4Network()` is similar, it takes your network address text and wraps it in a load of enhancements for working with IP networks.

**Containment**

When you do `IPv4Address(u'100.64.1.1') in IPv4Network(u'100.64.0.0/10')`, it's the extra enhancement code that understands what it means for one network to be "in" another.

In your question, your code is doing: `unicoded in ipaddress.IPv4Network(address)` and `unicoded` at that point is still just text.

`"word" in "sentence with some words"` is a way to test whether one string of text is *in* another, so your code is doing one-half of a text membership test and the other half of an IPv4Network membership test. And that mismatch causes the failure and the error you see. The IPv4Network object can't deal.

(The keyword `in` calls the [Python special method `__contains__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964934/what-does-contains-do-what-can-call-contains-function) behind the scenes to handle this kind of test).

**Comprehension**

In your other question asking about a nicer way to do things in Python (great thing to ask), the code goes from this shape of a classic `for` loop shape (example fake code):

```
for network in networks:
    test if address in network:
```

to this one-line shape:

```
[if address in network for network in networks]
```

That reshaped one-line version is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and it's a special case made for the common pattern of "doing something for every item in a list, and gathering up the results into another list". e.g.

```
>>> nums = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
>>> results = [num+1 for num in nums]

>>> results
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]

>>> results = = [num > 5 for num in nums]
[False, False, True, True, True, True]
```

(More specifically, without the `[` `]` on the outsides, it's the same thing but now called a [generator comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension), it's a newer version which is more memory efficient).

**any**

Then the `any()` function summarises a list down to one result. It considers a list in terms of truth values True/False, and returns True if *any*thing in the list is True. From above:

```
>>> results
[False, False, True, True, True, True]
>>> any(results)
True
```

(It goes with the `all()` function which tests if everything in the list is True).

So the line of code you get from combining all of these is:

```
if any(ipaddress.IPv4Address(unicoded) in ipaddress.IPv4Network(address) for address in ip4addressBlocks):
    print "it's reserved"
```

But (imho) that is still ugly. Partly it writes "ipaddress" a lot, partly it's building the enhanced objects over and over again, partly the variable name "ip4addressBlocks" doesn't explain anything about their significance, and partly you redundantly test true/false and then return true/false.

So, here, I:

- Import only the two names from the module, so I can use them directly without writing `ipaddress.` everywhere
- Build the reserved list IPv4Network objects once at the start
- Build the IPv4Address object once
- run the test and return the value directly, cutting out the "if true return true else return false"
- I'm not sure why you've put unicode and raw strings all over, but it seems unnecessary, so I've removed it.

e.g.:

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address, IPv4Network

reserved_networks = [IPv4Network(x) for x in [
    '0.0.0.0/8',      '10.0.0.0/8',     '100.64.0.0/10', '127.0.0.0/8', 
    '169.254.0.0/16', '172.16.0.0/12',  '192.0.0.0/24',  '192.0.2.0/24',      
    '192.88.99.0/24', '192.168.0.0/16', '198.18.0.0/15', '198.51.100.0/24',
    '203.0.113.0/24', '224.0.0.0/4',    '240.0.0.0/4',   '255.255.255.255/32'
    ]]

def isPrivateIp(ip):
    # True if ip is in a reserved range, otherwise False
    ip = IPv4Address(ip)
    return any((ip in net) for net in reserved_networks)

print isPrivateIp('179.254.255.1')
```

Comment: @TessellatingHecker What a superbly-written and thorough explanation, thank you.