# Grep/Sed/Awk Trim text around IP address in specific column to just leave the IP itself??

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, cut

I've been struggling with this issue for quite some time, I'm a beginner in using tools like grep/sed/awk/cut, as well as a beginner in regular expressions. I need to parse out a Cisco ASA Firewall log so that "columns" that contain an IP address are trimmed where only the IP address is left in its place. Please see the following example.

This:

`Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr [hostname_here]-[ip address]/[port] gaddr [ip address]/[port] laddr [ip address]/[port]`

Needs to be parsed out to this:

`Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr [ip address] gaddr [ip address] laddr [ip address]`

Honestly I don't think it's worth it to post what I've done so far because I'm sure I'm approaching this the wrong way.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you show some lines of sample data with your expected output.

Comment: Have you made any attempt whatsoever? Can we see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -rn  's/([fgl]addr )([^ -]*[ -])?(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\/[0-9]*/\1\3/gp' file
```

With `file` containing:

```
Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr google.com-129.244.54.55/63 gaddr 9.9.123.33/25 laddr 111.87.75.0/8444
```

Output:

```
Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 129.244.54.55 gaddr 9.9.123.33 laddr 111.87.75.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
egrep -o "(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" firewall.log
```

<sup>Source: [Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106179/55075)</sup>

To add some custom text for each of the addresses, add to above:

```
| while read ip; do echo "Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr $ip gaddr $ip laddr $ip"; done
```