# Is underscore support in hostname?

Tags: java, ping, hostname, inetaddress

In my unix vm, I can give the following entry in /etc/hosts
ABC_XYZ_HOSTNAME.abc.com 15.115.112.*** and after that I can "`ping ABC_XYZ_HOSTNAME.abc.com`" successfully. But my code is breaking at

```
InetAddresses.forString(ip)
```

with exception, IllegalArgumentException with IP string literal is not valid.

So the question is, is underscore supported hostname or something else is wrong here?

Comment: This post suggests that underscore isn't allowed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-dns-hostname-or-ip-address

Answer (score 2):

You can't use DNS names with `InetAddresses.forString`. The [javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html#forString-java.lang.String-) for this method states:

> Returns the InetAddress having the given string representation.
>
> This deliberately avoids all nameservice lookups (e.g. no DNS).
>
> Parameters:
>       ipString - String containing an IPv4 or IPv6 string literal, e.g. "192.168.0.1" or "2001:db8::1"

DNS name is not a valid value.

For [DNS lookup of your address](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)) you should use

```
InetAddress.getByName(host)
```

Comment: Question remains: Is underscore valid in hostname? Yes or No ?

Comment: Googling gives back the following result: The use of underscore characters is a little confusing. Underscore characters are not permitted in domain names in accordance with RFC 1035, which only allows letters, digits and hyphens. As such, you cannot register a domain name with an underscore character.