# Need to check srv pregmatch

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate srv record with jquery preg_match

What i need:  'PriorNumber WeightNumber PortNumber Address/server'.
This needs to be limited to max 5 parts in total.

For now i got a part working but only the last part is not working when i use a domain or ip address.

```
/^((\d+ \d+ \d+\w+.(?:\s+\w+)\1{0,1}$))/
```

Works = 100 1 4234 sipdsdfghj

Not working: 100 1 4234 sipdsdfghj.sadas

https://www.regextester.com/?fam=103214

Please help me on this

Full code validate

value = 100 1 4234 sipdsdfghj.asd

```
// Functie voor het valideren van srv record 'prioriteit gewicht poort doeladres'
jQuery.validator.addMethod("srvRecord", function(value, element) {
    if (value.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {

        console.log(value);

        if(value.match( /^(?<prior>\d+)\h+(?<weight>\d+)\h+(?<port>\d+)\h+(?:(?<ip>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})|(?<domain>\S+\.\S+))$/gm) !== null){
            return true;
        }

        return false
    } 
}, "* Amount must be greater than zero");
```

Comment: Maybe [`^(\d+)\h+(\d+)\h+(\d+)\h+(\S+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/o1HUBn/1) will suffice?

Comment: Nop. not even working on the last part

Comment: What last part? Note you provided no pattern requirements, it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: its like this, last part of the string that got check is an ip / domain and my expression is not seeing the . in the domain or ip as 1 input part.

Need to validate this input "100 1 4234 sipdsdfghj.sadas" or "100 1 4234 8.8.8.8"

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/o1HUBn/2

Comment: Seems to work on that page, but when using jquery is not.

if(value.match( /^(?<prior>\d+)\h+(?<weight>\d+)\h+(?<port>\d+)\h+(?:(?<ip>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})|(?<domain>\S+\.\S+))$/gm) !== null){
                return true;
            }

Comment: Then why at all use `java` and `preg_match` (PHP) tags? Show the whole code, provide a sample string(s) and state expected output. And only keep tags that are relevant.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: It is still not helpful since the code cannot be run as is. The only hint I can give now is that you need to replace `\h` with `\s` and remove capturing groups as you are not extracting anything, just "validating": `/^\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}|\S+\.\S+)$/`. Note you do not need `g` nor `m`.

Comment: This last one is working!

Comment: How can i do this for "number ip/domain"
Using: /^\d+ +.+/ but can add more after the second part so its not correct.

Comment: Do you mean `/^\d+\s+(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}|\S+\.\S+)$/`?

Comment: Yes that last one works correct.

Comment: can you do one more for this validation: "number ip/domain" ?

Comment: See above comment.

Comment: Not seems to work for:
100 8.8.8.8
100 mail.domain.tld

Comment: Can you still please assist me on the last one ?

Comment: [I already have](https://regex101.com/r/wnhg5Z/1).

Comment: Cheers! that one works good. Have a good day!

Comment: Can you help me on 1 more, need to check if input is between quote: "asdasasddsfsdfsdfsdfd"

Comment: I doubt that is related to the current issue. Moreover, what do you mean? `"[^"]+"` will match that string.

Comment: True, but still same category. That one works in browser but when i use it in the code i can put anyting behind the second " and its still validated.

Comment: If you need to match a *whole string*, add *anchors*. Read my answer, it can help you understand more about regex. Probably you need `/^"[^"]+"$/`. You can learn to write these patterns if you do the lessons at http://regexone.com. It is very short and helpful to learn the basics like you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this regex solution:

```
/^\d+(?:\s+\d+){2}\s+(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}|\S+\.\S+)$/
```

Note it does not really validate an IP or domain name, it only matches IP-like and domain-like substrings. See [Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-dns-hostname-or-ip-address) for details on a more precise IP regex.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\s+\d+){2}` - 2 sequences of 1+ whitespaces and 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}|\S+\.\S+)` - either of:

  - `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}` - 1 to 3 digits, and then 3 sequences of `.` and 1 to 3 digits
  - `\S+\.\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars, `.` and again 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.