# Python - Regex Ip that doesnt starts or ends with a dot

Tags: python, regex, ip

I have a regex that finds an ip:

```
'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}'
```

And now I need to make an Ip fail if it starts or ends with a dot.
For example, these will fail:

```
- .1.1.1.1
- 1.1.1.1.
- 1.1.1.1.1
- 1.11.1.1.1
```

Comment: Just use `^` and `$` anchors as shown [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/UJ3SzB/1)

Comment: does the input actually contain dashes and whitespaces `- .1.1.1.1` ? Show your current code: what is the input and how do you find IPs in it?

Comment: @Gurman I need to find the ip inside a large text, your example doesnt work

Comment: You may want to use a more sophisticated regex to match IPv4, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-dns-hostname-or-ip-address/106223#106223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<!\.)(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3})(?!\.)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UJ3SzB/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!\.)` - Negative lookbehind to make sure that your IP pattern is not preceded by a `.`
- `(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3})` - same as your pattern
- `(?!\.)` - Negative lookahead to make sure that your IP pattern is not followed by a `.`

Also, Note that, the IP pattern can also be improved, if required.

**Update**

As per your comment, here is the updated regex(I have just added word boundaries so as to cover the case provided by you):

[`(?<!\.)\b\d+(?:\.\d+){3}\b(?!\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/UJ3SzB/5)

Comment: Its almost what im looking for, expect, the following will also be found: - 1.11.1.1.1, ill get 1.1.1.1, and I dont want it