# Is this kind of regex possible without negative lookahead?

Tags: regex, re2

Basically the regex im looking to create is something that would match every domain `google` except `google.com` and `google.com.au`

So `google.org` `google.uk` or `google.com.pk` would be a match. Im working within the limitations of re2 and the best i've been able to come up with is

`google\.([^c][^o][^m]\.?[^a]?[^u]?)`

This doesnt work for the extended domains like `google.com.pk` and it doesnt work if the root is double digit eg. `.cn` instead of `.org` etc

It works if there's no extended domain and the root isnt two digit `google.org` matches `google.com` doesnt match

Here's the link with test cases.
regexr.com/7rbkn

Im looking for a workaround for negative lookahead. Or whether its possible to accomodate this within a single regex string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. The pattern will look a bit ugly, but what you are asking for is totally possible.

Let's assume that the input already satisfy the regex `google(?:\.[a-z]+)+` (i.e. `google` followed by at least one domain names) for ease of explanation. If you want more precision, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/106223).

### Match a name that is not a given name

The inverted of `com` would be:

- A name that is shorter or longer than 3, or
- A name of length 3 whose:

  - The first character is not `c`, or
  - The second character is not `o`, or
  - The third character is not `m`.

Translate that to regex and we have:

```
\A                    # This means "at the very start"
(?:
  [a-z]{1,2} |
  [a-z]{4,} |

  [^c.][a-z]{2} |     # Also exclude the dot,
  [a-z][^o.][a-z] |   # otherwise 'google.c.m'
  [a-z]{2}[^m.]       # would not match
)
\z                    # This means "at the very end"
```

The same applies to `au`:

```
\A(?:[a-z]|[a-z]{3,}|[^a.][a-z]|[a-z][^u.])\z
```

### Match a hostname that is not a given hostname

There are two cases you want to avoid: `google.com` and `google.com.au`. The inverted of that would be the union of the following cases:

- 1 extra names:

  - `google.*` where `*` is any name but `com`
- 2 extra names:

  - `google.*.*` where the first `*` is any name but `com`, or
  - `google.com.*` where `*` is any name but `au`
- 3 extra names or more: `google.*.*.* ...`

Or, a bit more logical:

- If the first name is not `com`, it doesn't matter how many names are left.

  - Any hostname following this pattern already differs from our exclude cases by one name.
- If the first name is `com` and the second name is not `au`, the rest of the names are also irrelevant.

  - ...for the exact same reason above.
- If the first and second names are `com` and `au` correspondingly, then there must be at least one other name, which means there are at least three extra names.

  - ...and if there are three extra names, then we don't need to check the first and the second at all.

That said, we only need three branches. Let <s>`com`</s> be the inverted of `com`, here's what the pattern looks like in pseudo-regex:

```
\A
(?:
  google\.com    (?:\.[a-z]+)*   |
  google\.com\.au(?:\.[a-z]+)*   |
  google         (?:\.[a-z]){3,}
)
\z
```

See the common parts? We can extract them out:

```
\A
google
(?:
  \.com          |
  \.com\.au      |
  (?:\.[a-z]){3}
)
(?:\.[a-z]+)*
\z
```

Insert what we had from section 1, and voilà.

### The final pattern

```
\A
google
(?:
  # google.com
  \.
  (?:
    [a-z]{1,2} | [a-z]{4,} |
    [^c.][a-z]{2} |
    [a-z][^o.][a-z] |
    [a-z]{2}[^m.]
  )
|
  # google.com.au
  \.com\.
  (?:
    [a-z] | [a-z]{3,} |
    [^a.][a-z] | [a-z][^u.]
  )
|
  # google.*.*.*
  (?:\.[a-z]+){3}
)
(?:\.[a-z]+)*
\z
```

Try it on regex101.com: [PCRE2 with comments](https://regex101.com/r/CC67Yd/1), [Go](https://regex101.com/r/CC67Yd/2), [multiline mode](https://regex101.com/r/CC67Yd/3).

Comment: It works on regex101 with Unit tests but not with the match option

Like if I give the test cases one below the other

google.com
google.com.au
google.au

Comment: @YRK Could you give a link? It [works fine](https://regex101.com/r/CC67Yd/4) for me. Note that the final pattern given here will only ever match exactly one at a time, with no surrounding whitespaces. The patterns given in the third link and the link in this comment were modified so that they could work in a multiline matching mode.

Comment: The updated one works :)

Answer (score 4):

With re2, where lookarounds are not available, you could use a "sacrificial match" as in [THIS](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) trick to match what you do not want but capture what you do want.

```
/(?:\bgoogle\.com$)|(?:\bgoogle\.com\.au$)|(\bgoogle\.\S*)/

if alone on a line or

/(?:\bgoogle\.com\s)|(?:\bgoogle\.com\.au\s)|(\bgoogle\.\S*\s)/

if followed by spaces...
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5IGuKk/1)

Limitations:

- Because `/google\.com/` will match `'google.com.pk'` the match items either need to be stand alone on a line or followed by a space that makes it obvious that `'.pk'` is not at the end. You can't use `\b` to detect the break between `.com` and `.com.pk` since `\b` is true in both cases.
- You need to have logic available to detect whether the match resulted in a capture. If the "sacrificial" matches on the left match first, the capture group will be empty. If the capture group is not empty, you have a match that is not one of the sacrificial matches.