# Regular expression for validating an ip address ,in ipv6 format

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression that matches valid IPv6 addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses)

Can any one know the regular expression

for validating an  ip address ,in ipv6 format

Comment: Not really a duplicate, because this question is about PHP and older question doesn't answer this problem in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$ipv6="2a01:e35:aaa4:6860:a5e7:5ba9:965e:cc93";
var_dump(filter_var($ipv6,FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6));
```

Answer (score 3):

If regex is not a solid requirement (I don't recommend it here), then:

```
if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6)) {
  // valid
}
else {
  // invalid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Net_IPv6](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_IPv6/redirected), with the function [checkIPv6()](http://pear.php.net/manual/de/package.networking.net-ipv6.checkipv6.php).

If you want to accept IPv4 and IPv6, try to use the function [filter_var()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
$valid = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
```

Comment: If you want the regex solution, it can be found within Net_IPv6's source.