# Javascript regular expression to validate URL

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I am validating URL with following regular expression. I want to validate **google.com** also but it returns false. What can be changed in R.E below to validate **google.com**.

```
console.log(learnRegExp('http://www.google-com.123')); // false
console.log(learnRegExp('https://www.google-com.com')); // true
console.log(learnRegExp('http://google-com.com')); // true
console.log(learnRegExp('http://google.com')); //true
console.log(learnRegExp('google.com')); //false

function learnRegExp(){
  return /^(ftp|https?):\/\/+(www\.)?[a-z0-9\-\.]{3,}\.[a-z]{3}$/.test(learnRegExp.arguments[0]);
}
```

Comment: are you trying to validate all url's or else you need only for 'google.com'?

Comment: Wrapping `(ftp|https?):\/\/+(www\.)?` with `( ... )?` will do. However, does this regex really suit your needs? I mean: `\.[a-z]{3}$` alone does exclude *many* valid URLs.

Comment: trying to validate all urls. ftp can be excluded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 112):

This validate the URL in general

```js
console.log('http://www.google-com.123.com', validateUrl('http://www.google-com.123.com')); // true 
console.log('http://www.google-com.123', validateUrl('http://www.google-com.123')); // false 
console.log('https://www.google-com.com', validateUrl('https://www.google-com.com')); // true 
console.log('http://google-com.com', validateUrl('http://google-com.com')); // true 
console.log('http://google.com', validateUrl('http://google.com')); //true 
console.log('google.com', validateUrl('google.com')); //false
console.log('http://www.gfh.', validateUrl('http://www.gfh.')); //false
console.log('http://www.gfh.c', validateUrl('http://www.gfh.c')); //false
console.log('http://www.gfh:800000', validateUrl('http://www.gfh:800000')); //false
console.log('www.google.com ', validateUrl('www.google.com ')); //false
console.log('http://google', validateUrl('http://google')); //false
console.log('//cdnblabla.cloudfront.net/css/app.css', validateUrl('//cdnblabla.cloudfront.net/css/app.css')); //true

function validateUrl(value) {
  return /^(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$/i.test(value);
}
```

**Should Match**

```js
["//www.google.com", "//cdnblabla.cloudfront.net/css/app.css", "http://✪df.ws/123", "http://userid:password@example.com:8080", "http://userid:password@example.com:8080/", "http://userid@example.com", "http://userid@example.com/", "http://userid@example.com:8080", "http://userid@example.com:8080/", "http://userid:password@example.com", "http://userid:password@example.com/", "http://142.42.1.1/", "http://142.42.1.1:8080/", "http://➡.ws/䨹", "http://⌘.ws", "http://⌘.ws/", "http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-1", "http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1", "http://foo.com/unicode_(✪)_in_parens", "http://foo.com/(something)?after=parens", "http://☺.damowmow.com/", "http://code.google.com/events/#&product=browser", "http://j.mp", "ftp://foo.bar/baz", "http://foo.bar/?q=Test%20URL-encoded%20stuff", "http://مثال.إختبار", "http://例子.测试"].map(function(url) {
  console.log(url, validateUrl(url));
});

function validateUrl(value) {
  return /^(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$/i.test(value);
}
```

**Should Fail**

```js
["http://", "http://.", "http://..", "http://../", "http://?", "http://??", "http://??/", "http://#", "http://##", "http://##/", "http://foo.bar?q=Spaces should be encoded", "//", "//a", "///a", "///", "http:///a", "foo.com", "rdar://1234", "h://test", "http:// shouldfail.com", ":// should fail", "http://foo.bar/foo(bar)baz quux", "ftps://foo.bar/", "http://-error-.invalid/", "http://-a.b.co", "http://a.b-.co", "http://0.0.0.0", "http://10.1.1.0", "http://10.1.1.255", "http://224.1.1.1", "http://1.1.1.1.1", "http://123.123.123", "http://3628126748", "http://.www.foo.bar/", "http://www.foo.bar./", "http://.www.foo.bar./", "http://10.1.1.1", "http://10.1.1.254"].map(function(url) {
  console.log(url, validateUrl(url));
});

function validateUrl(value) {
  return /^(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$/i.test(value);
}
```

**How it works**

```
// protocol identifier
"(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?//)"
// user:pass authentication
"(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?"
"(?:"
// IP address exclusion
// private & local networks
"(?!(?:10|127)(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})"
"(?!(?:169\\.254|192\\.168)(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})"
"(?!172\\.(?:1[6-9]|2\\d|3[0-1])(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})"
// IP address dotted notation octets
// excludes loopback network 0.0.0.0
// excludes reserved space >= 224.0.0.0
// excludes network & broacast addresses
// (first & last IP address of each class)
"(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])"
"(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}"
"(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))"
"|"
// host name
"(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)"
// domain name
"(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*"
// TLD identifier
"(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))"
// port number
"(?::\\d{2,5})?"
// resource path
"(?:[/?#]\\S*)?"
```

All this comes from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294), i hope that this fill all your needs

Comment: I applaud you for or the longest and most incomprehensible regex I've ever seen.

Comment: Also this fits the OP needs, it does not validate URL in general.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i already updated the code to fix your worries

Comment: this fails for `localhost` and any of kind `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Doesn't match localhost. Do not use.

Comment: If URL contains capital letter then it fails.

Comment: @V.J. then, convert url to lowerCase before validating. you could use `.toLowerCase()` in javascript on a string value

Comment: like this is not valid input pattern. My input field won't validate after I have written correct URL.

Comment: sorry! man, it's working now, I just needed to remove the two (open and close) slash `/`.

Answer (score 9):

This is perfect for me. I hope it will be perfect for someone else! :)

`/^((https?):\/\/)?([w|W]{3}\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{3,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?$/`

Comment: What does this answer provide that the earlier answers don't already provide?

Comment: @Louis which previous answers?

Comment: this is much better than the most voted answer which doesn't work cause accepts anything like ww.google  or www.google or www.google.c  ....but yours works perfectly....nice job

Comment: This also only accepts URLs in the www subdomain. URls such as https://developers.facebook.com/ will not pass this check. Replacing + with * fixes that though.

Comment: @Steve yes but then this would pass https://.google.com

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, you need to make "ftp/http(s)://" not a MUST. Use "?" for this.

```
function learnRegExp(){
  return /((ftp|https?):\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-z0-9\-\.]{3,}\.[a-z]{3}$/.test(learnRegExp.arguments[0]);
}
```

Comment: As you can see, I only wrapped your `(ftp|https?):\/\/` into `()?`.

Comment: How do I make it not to match a http / https?

Comment: @San Replace `(ftp|https?)` with `ftp`

Answer (score 1):

```
/(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
```

Comment: Looks like google.com is not validating.Added some code to validate. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`^...` symbol is saying begins with so the final log makes sense, i.e. the string does not begin with ftp or http(s). Youre also saying with `...$` that the end that the string must finish with three letters which again where it fails (line 2) it does not end like this. Some minor adjustments and you should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have multiple regex for each case?

1. Valid alphanumeric url: `/^https?:\/\/([\w\d\-]+\.)+\w{2,}(\/.+)?$/`

   Works with `http://sub_do-main.a.co` to things like `https://a.a.a.a.aa/my-awesome_url?asd=12`. You can try it at: https://regex101.com/r/oXFuGy/2
2. IPv4, short and fast but not 100% accurate (it is used by validator.js): `/^(\d{1,3}(\.|$)){4}/`. It allows things like `999.999.999.999.`
3. IPv4, larger, slower but 100% accurate: `^(((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d{2})|(\d{1,2}))\.){3}(((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d{2})|(\d{1,2})))$`. Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50650510/2862917.
4. IPv6 (I don't know exactly if this is the best/accurate/faster approach: `^(([\da-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[\da-fA-F]{0,4})$`. Found it here: [Regular expression that matches valid IPv6 addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses) which has as a first answer why would be better to stop using regex to try to validate IP's (at least those v6).