# url validation jquery using regex

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, url

I want to validate URLs of the following form:

1. http://www.example.com
2. http://example.com
3. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

```
function is_valid_url(url) {
    return /^http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/.test(url);
}
```

1 and 2 are validated correctly. But 3 shows an invalid URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667070/javascript-regular-expression-to-validate-url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, It worked for me.

```
var url = $("#<%= txtUrl.ClientID %>").val();
var pattern = /^(http|https)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/;

args.IsValid = pattern.test(url);
```

http://www.tricksofit.com/2013/12/regular-expression-with-jquery-validation#highlighter_290011

Comment: This is okay if user not typing the www. Means it will be fine if user types "https:// yahoo.i" (shows error). But if user types it like "https:// www.yahoo.i" , this will not show any error and validates.

Answer (score 17):

That's the correct regular expression for your use case:

```
function is_valid_url(url) {
    return /^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/.test(url);
}
```

If "http://" is optional, you will have to put it in brackets and add a question mark.

Answer (score 2):

We need to validate n number of scenarios for URL validation. If your particular about your given pattern then above regex expression from other answer looks good.
 that is :

```
    function is_valid_url(url) 
{
   return /^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/.test(url);
}
```

Or

If you want to take care of all the URL validation scenarios please [refer In search of the perfect URL validation regex](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex)