# URL-checking regular expression running endless in browser

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following regular expression to check if URLs are valid

```
var re = /^(http[s]?:\/\/(www\.)?|ftp:\/\/(www\.)?|www\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\.@:%_+~#=]+)+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\?(.)*)?/;
var is_valid = re.test(input_url);
```

It works with small inputs, but starts to run endless with larger inputs. Consider the following 64-characters input

```
re.test("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

Running this won't complete within minutes when running with an up-to-date Google Chrome.

Is there a problem with the regular expression?

Comment: [Catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) with nested quantifiers in `([0-9A-Za-z-\.@:%_+~#=]+)+` ... Remove one of the `+`... Change to  `([0-9A-Za-z-\.@:%_+~#=]+)`

Comment: There are other bottlenecks here, the problem is one: nested quantifiers of various types.

Comment: @Mariano great, thank you!

Comment: Besides the backtracking issues, this regex doesn't come close to verifying a URL.  For example, these would be valid: `www.........abc!!!!!!!!!!!!`, `www.@.foo`, `www.abc.com'; drop table user;`

Comment: There's also an unscaped `/` too. I doubt it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hanging is due to [backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), as Mariano mentioned in the comments.  A regex that has multiple quantifiers such as * and + can result in there being way too many possible permutations of potential matches, and the engine hangs forever while trying to explore them all when a string doesn't match.

However, beyond this the regex has multiple problems and is not fit for purpose.  I suggest you start over with one of the methods from previous questions on this topic:

[Trying to Validate URL Using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303872/trying-to-validate-url-using-javascript)

[Javascript regular expression to validate URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667070/javascript-regular-expression-to-validate-url)