# need a regex to check whether URl entered is valid in typescript

Tags: regex, typescript, url, match

From research of the same,i came to find none of the suggested URL's matching my criteria, thus raised a new query.

Following are my requirements :
* The URL may or may not contain a 'http' or 'https'
* The URL can be directly an IP address with a port number.

Examples that should pass:

- http://abcd.nju.in
- flower.insu-rge.ui
- 192.89.32.4:8989
- https://170.45.6.7
- 172.36.23.5

Invalid Urls:

- http://
- http://test.
- 192.56.
- 192.65
- test.xyz

Comment: Why is test.xyz invalid whereas flower.insu-rge.ui valid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript regular expression to validate URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667070/javascript-regular-expression-to-validate-url)

Comment: The url's used in my application have minimum three sections, thus test.xyz is invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the **provided input strings/examples**, I could come up with the following regex. It is long but it does cover the scenarios mentioned by you.

Regex:

```
^(?![^\n]*\.$)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:[2][1-4]\d|25[1-5]|1\d{2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9])(?:\.(?:[2][1-4]\d|25[1-5]|1\d{2}|[1-9]\d|[0-9])){3}(?::\d{4})?|[a-z\-]+(?:\.[a-z\-]+){2,})$
```

[Click for DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ywrtaN/1)

**EXPLANATION:**

- `^` - Start of the string
- `(?![^\n]*\.$)` - Negative Lookahead to validate that the string does not end with `.`
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?` - Optional `http://` or `https://`
- `(?:[2][1-4]\d|25[1-5]|1\d{2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9])(?:\.(?:[2][1-4]\d|25[1-5]|1\d{2}|[1-9]\d|[0-9])){3}(?::\d{4})?` - Regular expression for a valid IP address followed by an optional port number(`:XXXX`)
- `|` - OR
- `[a-z\-]+(?:\.[a-z\-]+){2,}` - To match strings like `flower.insu-rge.ui`
- `$` - End of String

Comment: I used the above regex in my typescript file but still i m getting a mismatch on all the examples that i have stated above.

Comment: I did : let urlRegex = '(?![^\n]*\.$)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:[2][1-4]\d|25[1-5]|1\d{2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9])(?:\.(?:[2][1-4]\d|25[1-5]|1\d{2}|[1-9]\d|[0-9])){3}(?::\d{4})?|[a-z\-]+(?:\.[a-z\-]+){2,})'; and checked control.value.match(urlRegex) : this returns invalid status

Comment: you can further test the regex from regex101.com

Comment: the same regex used on multiple regex test platforms gives appropriate results,I am not able to use this in my typescript class, am i doing something wrong,syntax wise?

Comment: I could only help you with the regex as I am not familiar with the typescript syntax. This regex even works for Javascript flavor(as can be seen here -
 https://regex101.com/r/ywrtaN/2).

Comment: Yes it does work there too, i am not able to figure out why this regex is returning invalid with the same examples that are passed by the javascript flavor.

Comment: The URL worked, i needed to enclose the regex with '/gm' flag, which i didn't before.