# How Can I Validate a URL end point in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate the url end point using regex. Example end point like: /user/update.

First I tried with (/[A-Za-z0-9_.:-~/]*) but also matches http://url.com/user/update with javascript regex. I want the string to only validate pass if it is equal to /user/update like end points

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript regular expression to validate URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667070/javascript-regular-expression-to-validate-url)

Comment: No @Yogi it explains how to validate full url. I want to validate the string which only contain endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` look behind technique to get the path after the `.com` with `/(?<=.com).*/`

```js
const matchEndPoint = (str) => str.match(/(?<=.com).*/)

const [result] = matchEndPoint('http://url.com/user/update');

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a pattern like

```
^\/[\w.:~-]+\/[\w.:~-]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/naAWtr/1)

Or for example not allowing consecutive dashes like `--` and match one or more forward slashes:

```
^\/\w+(?:[.:~-]\w+)*(?:\/\w+(?:[.:~-]\w+)*)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\/\w+` Match / and 1+ word chars
- `(?:[.:~-]\w+)*` Optionally repeat a char of the character class and 1+ word chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\/\w+` Match / and 1+ word chars
  - `(?:[.:~-]\w+)*` Optionally repeat a char of the character class and 1+ word chars
- `)*` Close group and optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nYoesu/1)