# How to parse IPv6 address into byte array in Lua?

Tags: lua, ipv6

Any easy way to detect if an IP is a valid IPv6 and also if it is valid, how to parse it to get the byte array?

Currently using ZeroBrane Studio IDE and the integrated Lua version is 5.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lua function check if ipv4 or ipv6 or string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975935/lua-function-check-if-ipv4-or-ipv6-or-string)

Answer (score 1):

As part of the [answer on how to check if the IPv6 address is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10984133/1442917), the string is parsed into a table, which you can use for your purposes:

```
-- assuming you already check that the string has IPv6 format
local ip = "1050:0000:0000:0000:0005:0600:300c:326b"
local chunks = {ip:match(("([a-fA-F0-9]*):"):rep(8):gsub(":$","$"))}
print(table.concat(chunks, ":"))
```