# Rails 3 validate IPv4 and IPv6 format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, ip-address

I know the validation format for IPv4 and IPv6. But not sure how I can combine them so atleast one format should be true. Here is my validation

```
validates :src_ip_addr, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true,
            :format => { :with => Resolv::IPv4::Regex, :message => "Not an valid IPv4 format"}

  validates :src_ip_addr, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true,
            :format => { :with => Resolv::IPv6::Regex, :message => "Not an valid IPv6 format"}
```

How I can combine them so if one format is correct then validation should work. Should fail only if ipv4 and ipv6 format is not correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also combine them with `Regexp.union`:

```
:format => { :with => Regexp.union(Resolv::IPv4::Regex, Resolv::IPv6::Regex) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```rb
:format => { :with => Resolv::AddressRegex ...
```

...to match both IPv4 and IPv6.