# Extract IP out of string with Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.3, logfile

I just had a look at regex and I'm a bit confused.
I wrote a program which analyses the "auth.log" file in realtime, line by line.
Now I need different informations out of the entries.

```
if "sshd" in line
    if "Accepted password" in line
        REGEX Query to get the username and ip
    elif "session closed" in line
        REGEX Query to get the username
```

This are the entries in the log file:

```
Nov 29 13:20:33 Debian sshd[4043]: Accepted password for patrick from ::1 port 50864 ssh2
Nov 29 13:20:33 Debian sshd[4043]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user patrick by (uid=0)
Nov 29 13:21:23 Debian sshd[4043]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user patrick
```

Which Tool should I choose to do this? re.search?

Comment: [Start by reading the manual](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). It won't take long, trust me.

Comment: You should do at least give it a try, when you stuck come ask the real problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since log entries are strongly formatted, you might not need to use a regex:

```
$ cat t.txt 
Nov 29 13:20:33 Debian sshd[4043]: Accepted password for patrick from ::1 port 50864 ssh2
Nov 29 13:20:33 Debian sshd[4043]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user patrick by (uid=0)
Nov 29 13:21:23 Debian sshd[4043]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user patrick
$ cat t.py 
#/usr/bin/env python
for line in open('t.txt'):
    if "sshd" in line:
        if "Accepted password" in line:
            print "User: ", line.split()[8]
            print "IP: ", line.split()[10]
        if "session closed" in line:
            print "User: ", line.split()[10]
$ python t.py 
User:  patrick
IP:  ::1
User:  patrick
```

Of course you need to be more careful with lines like `if "sshd" in line:` but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I find IPv6 and IPv4 addresses:

```
import re
ip6 =   '''(?:(?x)(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,1}(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,6})|
(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,2}(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,5})|
(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,3}(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,4})|
(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,4}(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,3})|
(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,5}(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,2})|
(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,6}(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,1})|
(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,7}|:):)|
(?::(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,7})|
(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6})(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}))|
(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}))|
(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})|
(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,1}(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,4}:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})|
(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,2}(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,3}:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})|
(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,3}(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,2}:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})|
(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,4}(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,1}:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})|
(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,5}|:):(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})|
(?::(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,5}:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}))
'''
ip4 =   '(?:[12]?\\d?\\d\\.){3}[12]?\\d?\\d'
ip = re.findall(ip4 + '|' + ip6, "111:111::1 1.1.1.1")
```

I got the regex for IPv6 from an other website [Regular expression that matches valid IPv6 addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses)