# Regex that only validates IPv6 address in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, ipv6

I need a regular expression that only validates an IPv6 address in Javascript.  I have tried the following two which both fail on a string like 1:1:1:1:1:1:1:1

```
^([\dA-F]{1,4}:|((?=.*(::))(?!.*\3.+\3))\3?)([\dA-F]{1,4}(\3|:\b)|\2){5}(([\dA-F]{1,4}(\3|:\b|$)|\2){2}|(((2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d|25[0-5])\.?\b){4})\z

^([0-9A-Fa-f]{0,4}:){2,7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}$|((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4})$
```

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't think your link is a duplicate. The answers are for C# in that question, unless I misread them.

Comment: @xxbbcc: In particular, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17871737/47453) of that question.

Comment: @sharth You could be right - I haven't looked through every single answer.

Comment: Why is this question voted down?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

here you go

```
[0-9a-fA-F].{0,3}+:[0-9a-fA-F].{0,3}+:[0-9a-fA-F].{0,3}+:[0-9a-fA-F].{0,3}+:[0-9a-fA-F].{0,3}+:[0-9a-fA-F].{0,3}+:[0-9a-fA-F].{0,3}+:[0-9a-fA-F].{0,3}
```

oops, forgot to set it to a max of 4 per segment.

Note that there are spcific combinations for ip address where some are not valid. But this will fit your requirment.

Comment: -1 : your regex fails to accept `::1` which is the IPv6 loopback address.

Comment: Are you sure that you want the dots between the `[...]` and the `{...}`?

Comment: Fixed issue from sharth's comment, thanks. I don't know regular expression enough to fix the issue noted in xxbbcc''ss comment

Comment: @JosephDailey IPv6 addresses are fairly complex. I wouldn't use a regex to check them but a proper parser. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address

Comment: I know how ipv6 works to an extent but when validating that somthing is 64bit hex values separated by colons, this would suffice.