# Regex: How to match IPv6 address ending in ::\d+ (Python)?

Tags: python, regex

The regex given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses/17871737#17871737) for IPv6 addresses works well for most IPv6 address I am looking to extract.

But it falls short with address **2607:f8b0:4001:c03::247** (mail-ie0-x247.google.com), matching only up to and including the last two colons thus **2607:f8b0:4001:c03::**

How would we extend the regex (for Python) such that it catches cases like this (without breaking it for other variants? I'm not sure how Google sets up its IPv6 addresses, but I guess it's conceivable that the characters coming after the last two colons could be a mixture of both letters and numbers, so the regex should handle this also.

Comment: Please also give the code tried by you here.

Comment: It seems to work here: https://regex101.com/r/dO9qK8/1

Comment: @shivams If I read regex101 correctly, is that regex actually producing two matches? Also, when I run the generated Python code, I get no matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to avoid using RegEx wherever you can, because implemting this manually often leads to errors (e.g. you can not check if this RegEx actually works for **every** possible IPv6 address).

Some better solution (in my opinion) is using the python built-in [ip adress manipulation library](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ipaddress.html):

```
import ipaddress

sample_addr = "2001:db8::"

try:
    # executed if (and only if) ip address is valid
    ipaddress.ip_address(sample_addr)
except ValueError:
    print "address invalid"
    # further error handling
```

`ip_address()` returns an IPv6 or IPv4 object (in dependence of the input) or raises a ValueError if the input was non-valid.

Comment: Now THAT's thinking outside of the box. However, I've tried the above code on a few valid IPv4 and IPv6 addresses e.g. 23.37.21.100, and I get a ValueError each time.

Comment: Update: On Python 2, it seems I need to make the string unicode. Works well now. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes, should have mentioned that...sry^^