# IPV6 address validation using shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am using below script to validate IPV6 address but this script also pass invalid IP such as empty string, name etc.

```
if [[ "$IPv6ADDR"=~"^:?([a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}(:|.)?){0,8}(:|::)?([a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}(:|.)?){0,8}$" ]]; then
  echo "valid ipv6 addr"
else
  echo "Invalid IP Address"
fi
```

Can someone identify what's wrong in the regex, please?

Comment: The most basic error is that you need whitespace on both sides of the `=~` operator.

Comment: You probably don't want to use a [regular expression for IPv6 addresses](http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/05/working-ipv6-regular-expression/).

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it passes an empty string is that all of your content is optional or allowed to match 0 times:

- `^` - match beginning of string
- `:?` - optional colon
- `([a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}(:|.)?){0,8}` - matches 0 - 8 times (thus optional)
- `(:|::)?` - optional colon or double colon
- `([a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}(:|.)?){0,8}` - matches 0 - 8 times (thus optional)
- `$` - matches end of string

Thus a blank string is allowed, as your pattern allows a string to not match any of the optional parts.

---

Looking at RFC 4291, which defines the IP 6 specification, [section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.2) defines three methods of representing the address.  It may be easiest, if you need to match all forms to define them separately and combine the separate regex's together, as in

```
^(regex_pattern1|regex_pattern2|regex_pattern3)$
```

where pattern1, for example, is `(?:[A-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}[A-F0-9]{1,4}` and patterns 2 and 3 are for the other cases (pattern 1 taken from *Regular Expressions Cookbook, 2nd Edition* (O'Reilly, 2012))

Or, even better (for readability), test them in serial (pseudocode follows),

```
if (matches pattern 1)
    echo 'valid'
else if (matches pattern 2)
    echo 'valid'
else if (matches pattern 3)
    echo 'valid'
else
    echo 'invalid'
```

See, also, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses) for some more information.

Comment: Thanks Mathew for the valuable input.

Comment: @user2145274, You're welcome. If you find an answer helpful, please consider accepting it. You are under no obligation to do so, but this awards both the author and yourself with a small amount of reputation, and lists the question as answered. Remember also that you can upvote particularly helpful answers on your own questions or any other question.