# validation of ipv6 using regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash, ipv6

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the ip addresss"
read n
if [[ $n =~ ^(
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|          # 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|                         # 1::                              1:2:3:4:5:6:7::
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|         # 1::8             1:2:3:4:5:6::8  1:2:3:4:5:6::8
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|  # 1::7:8           1:2:3:4:5::7:8  1:2:3:4:5::8
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|  # 1::6:7:8         1:2:3:4::6:7:8  1:2:3:4::8
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|  # 1::5:6:7:8       1:2:3::5:6:7:8  1:2:3::8
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|  # 1::4:5:6:7:8     1:2::4:5:6:7:8  1:2::8
[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|       # 1::3:4:5:6:7:8   1::3:4:5:6:7:8  1::8  
:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|                     # ::2:3:4:5:6:7:8  ::2:3:4:5:6:7:8 ::8       ::     
fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|     # fe80::7:8%eth0   fe80::7:8%1     (link-local IPv6 addresses with zone index)
::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}
((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}
(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|          # ::255.255.255.255   ::ffff:255.255.255.255  ::ffff:0:255.255.255.255  (IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses and IPv4-translated addresses)
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:
((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}
(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])           # 2001:db8:3:4::192.0.2.33  64:ff9b::192.0.2.33 (IPv4-Embedded IPv6 Address)
) ]]; then

        echo "valid ipv6 address"
else
        echo "not valid"
fi
```

I trying to validate ipv6 address by this script.but the script is not working properly..When iam giving my link local as input its not acceting that as valid ipv6 address

This is the result

```
enter the ip addresss
 fe80::dacb:8aff:fe0c        
not valid
```

Some one could help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Please use the github link posted by the author in this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/17871737/5291015

Comment: both codes are same....please check