# How to disable DNS resolving in Python socket module?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, dns

I have an application that needs to implement no-DNS option. Therefore either question, whichever is convenient:

- How can I differentiate a string IP address from a string hostname (domain)?
- How can I disable DNS globally in Python socket module?

To asnwer what the no-DNS option mean, supposed to do: I think it makes sure that domain hostnames are not resolved at all, program just exists with an error instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to distinguish IP numbers from hostnames.

For ipv4, that's trivial:

```
import re

def is_ipv4(host):
    m = re.search(r'^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$', host)
    return m is not None
```

I defer David Syzdek for the [more complex ipv6 case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses#17871737):

```
    m = re.search(r'(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))', host)
```

Or, rather than go the regex route, see if calling [`socket.inet_pton()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.inet_pton) (twice) will raise OSError.