# Java IPv6 segment validation

Tags: ipv6

Java。
I need to verify whether the IPv6 network segment is legal。Who has had the same problem? Thank you。

com.google.common.net.InetAddresses。Only IPv6 format can be verified

```html
/**
   * Returns {@code true} if the supplied string is a valid IP string literal, {@code false}
   * otherwise.
   *
   * @param ipString {@code String} to evaluated as an IP string literal
   * @return {@code true} if the argument is a valid IP string literal
   */
  public static boolean isInetAddress(String ipString) {
    return ipStringToBytes(ipString) != null;
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean you want to see if an IPv6 address is a valid format (uncompressed, compressed, uncompressed-hybrid, compressed-hybrid, brackets for URI, include a zone ID and/or prefix length, etc.)? What have you tried? There area lot of regular expressions out there that cover part or all of the valid IPv6 text representations. One of the more complete is in [this anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871737/3745413)

Comment: I need to verify whether the IPv6 network segment entered by the user is a legal network segment

Comment: What does that mean? Do you mean a valid text format?

Comment: Yes。uncompressed，compressed。

Comment: There are all types of regular expressions here, and I pointed you to a very complete one. Just search [so] for `ipv6 regular expression`, and you will find many, many answers.

Comment: ([A-Fa-f0-9]{0,4}::?){2,7}[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,4} cant match FE80::212:34FF::FE00:ABCD

Comment: Your example, `FE80::212:34FF::FE00:ABCD` is not a valid IPv6 text representation because you cannot have two `::` in the address.

Comment: I'm trying. I come from China. This is my first time to ask for help in stack overflow. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's what I mean. But return true。

Comment: How to combine regular expressions. ([A-Fa-f0-9]{0,4}::?){2,7}[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,4} And ::?

Comment: Look at the answer I linked in my first comment. It will validate all to correct forms.

Comment: I want to validate like this. ‘FE80:0:0:CD30::/60’ . I didn't find it in the anser.