# Ip host script bash

Tags: bash, ip, host

In the first if we want the hostname to appear, which is the 5th field from a file. Then if the IP we give to the host command does not exist, then the command returns message 3 (NXDOMAIN). The script should recognize if the command was "not found". In this case it will
must simply print (-).

```
#!/bin/bash
ip="$1"

if [ "$ip" ] ; then
         host "$ip" | cut -d' ' -f5

 elif
         [[ "$ip" =~ "[3(NXDOMAIN)]$" ]] ; then
                echo "-"
fi
```

Do u have any solution on this exercise?

Comment: When the name exists, the IP is in the 4th field. Also, `host` can print multiple lines of output.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 2):

You're not testing the result of the `host` command, you're testing the value of the original `$ip` variable.

Save the output to a variable, test that variable, then either print the output or `-` depending on the test.

You don't need to do a regexp match, just match the exact string.

```
#!/bin/bash
ip="$1"

if [ "$ip" ] ; then
    result=$(host "$ip" | cut -d" " -f5)
    if [[ $result = "3(NXDOMAIN)" ]] ; then
        echo "-"
    else
        echo "$result"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i want cut to print just the 5th field of the file though which is the hostname.

Comment: The output looks like: `www.google.com has address 172.217.10.228`. There's no 5th field when it succeeds. The hostname is in the 1st field, the address is in the 4th field.

Comment: Unless you're talking about `www.google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4006:810::2004` the IPv6 address is in the 5th field

Comment: Its kinda like that: ip address.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer hostname.

Comment: Of course. I should have realized that you're doing reverse DNS because it's `$ip` not `$hostname`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is much simpler than you think, you don't need to do ***any*** matching.  You can just use the return code from `host`

```
#!/bin/bash
ip="$1"

if domain=$(host "$1"); then
  echo "${domain##* }"
else
  echo "-"
fi
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ testHost(){ if domain=$(host "$1"); then echo "${domain##* }"; else echo "-"; fi }
$ testHost 172.217.6.46
sfo03s08-in-f14.1e100.net.
$ testHost 172.217.6.466
-
```

Comment: have searched for `host` exit status but didn't find anything - do you know meanings (besides usual 0,1)?

Comment: @alecxs looks like it's just success --> 1, failure --> 0.   That's not that uncommon with utils

Comment: @alecxs you didn't get the memo? Today is backwards day :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

if  [ -n "$1" ] && [[ $1 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+$ ]] ;then

    res=$(host "$1" | cut -d' ' -f5)

    if [ "$res" != "3(NXDOMAIN)" ]; then
        echo "$res"
    else
        echo "-"
    fi

else
    echo "please enter a valid ip"
fi
```

Comment: you could check for `host` non-zero (1-255) exit status maybe `$?` returns 3 (and `host -4` will skip IPv6)

Comment: @alecxs thank you for your input. In some bash versions like on debian host -4 and -6 is not supported

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cover also ipv6 then I think this will cover it

```
#!/bin/bash

# ipv4
if [[ $1 =~ ^([[:digit:]]{1,2}|1[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]|2[0-4][[:digit:]]|25[0-5])\.([[:digit:]]{1,2}|1[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]|2[0-4][[:digit:]]|25[0-5])\.([[:digit:]]{1,2}|1[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]|2[0-4][[:digit:]]|25[0-5])\.([[:digit:]]{1,2}|1[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]|2[0-4][[:digit:]]|25[0-5])$ ]]; then

    res=`host "$1" | cut -d' ' -f5`

    if [ "$res" != "3(NXDOMAIN)" ]; then
        echo "$res"
    else
        # valid ipv4 IP but not connected
        echo "-"
    fi

# ipv6
elif [[ $1 =~ ^(([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){7,7}[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}|([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){1,6}:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}|([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}){1,2}|([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}){1,3}|([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}){1,4}|([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}){1,5}|[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:((:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[[:xdigit:]]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[[:digit:]]){0,1}[[:digit:]])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[[:digit:]]){0,1}[[:digit:]])|([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[[:digit:]]){0,1}[[:digit:]])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[[:digit:]]){0,1}[[:digit:]]))$ ]]; then

    res=`host "$1" | cut -d' ' -f5`

    if [ "$res" != "3(NXDOMAIN)" ]; then
        echo "1. $res"
    else
        # valid ipv6 IP but not connected
        echo "2. -"
    fi

else

    echo "Please enter a valid IP"
fi
```

Note: For some versions of bash the -4 and -6 options do not work.

Thanks to Léa Gris for pointing out the locales problem.

Inspired from https://helloacm.com/how-to-valid-ipv6-addresses-using-bash-and-regex/

Comment: Your regex is only valid within some locales and will fail on Turkish locale and others with very different alphabet and digits. Use `[[:xdigit:]]` for hexadecimal numbers and `[[:digit:]]` for decimal ones instead.

Comment: @LéaGris thank you for you input, can you give me a example of a turkish ipv6 with turkish locales ?

Comment: `[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}` will match with `bäd` and it is not a valid hexadecimal number.

Comment: With Turkish Alphabet. `echo 'abçd' | grep -oE '[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}'` wrongly match the `ç` witch is invalid for an hexadecimal number. Whereas matching with `echo 'abçd' | grep -oE '[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}'` you can see it is excluded from the match.

Comment: @LéaGris you could answer here too (may helpful to others) https://stackoverflow.com/a/37355379