# using bash with sed how to extract ip from a host command and saving it in /etc/hosts file

Tags: bash, sed

I was wondering if there is a way to write to /etc/hosts file an entry by doing the following using a bash script (.sh)

1. Get the ip of a host command for e.g. (could be any URL)

> host cloud.com

2. The reslt would be as follows:

> cloud.com has address 50.17.245.212

3. Finally, I want to insert into the **/etc/hosts** file the following:

> 50.17.245.212 ip-50-17-245-212

Note: First IP is of the URL and then followed by that it is prefixed with **-ip** and then dots are replaced with "-"

I tried with dig but the result is long, would appreciate any pointers here.

Comment: ... and why would you even want this? So you have an URL, you check if the website exists, and in case it does, instead of adding it to the /etc/hosts file (like the entry "cloud.com     50.17.245.212" you invent another hostname, purely based on the IP, and add this to the /etc/hosts file without reference to the original URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ip host script bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62182898/ip-host-script-bash)

Comment: @alecxs - not quite

Comment: @Dominique - It is for an experiment. I know what you're saying but need to do it.

Comment: *ip=$(host cloud.com | cut -d ' ' -f4); echo "$ip ip-${ip//+([.:])/-}" >> /etc/hosts* or use [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37355379) for catching valid ipv4/ipv6 address instead of *cut*

Comment: @alecxs - do you want to post your response as a proper answer, i will accept it.

Comment: The proper way to use dig is with +short (`dig +short cloud.com`) but alexcs' oneliner works regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url=cloud.com
```

#### whitespace as delimiter for `cut` to print only 4th field

```
ip=$(host $url | cut -d ' ' -f4)
```

#### or regex for grep only valid ipv4/ipv6

```
ip=$(host $url | grep -ioE '([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}) | (([a-f0-9:]+:+)+[a-f0-9]+)')
```

#### echo variable `${ip}` with string manipulation `//` replace `+()` multiple occurences of `[.:]` dots or colons `/` with `-`

```
echo "$ip ip-${ip//+([.:])/-}" | tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 3):

A single (GNU) `sed` command:

```
host cloud.com |
sed -E -n 's/.* has address (([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)).*/\1 ip-\2-\3-\4-\5/p'
```

Redirect the output as needed such as `>> /etc/hosts`