# Python Regexp Dynamic Search

Tags: python, regex

I have written regexp to search all 4 values under host-vpp1out (up):
So basically I want the regexp to be dynamic so that it can capture any no of IPv4/IPv6 address under "host-vpp1out (up):"

```
m = re.findall(r'host-vpp1out.*\n\s+L3\s+(\d[\d.]*)', out)
```

current output

```
['1.1.1.1']
```

expected

```
['1.1.1.1', '1.1.2.1', '2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1', '2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:1']
```

### out

```
VirtualFuncEthernet0/7/0.2001 (up):
  L3 1.1.2.2/24 ip4 table-id 8 fib-idx 2
  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:2/112 ip6 table-id 8 fib-idx 1
VirtualFuncEthernet0/9/0 (dn):
host-vpp1out (up):
  L3 1.1.1.1/24
  L3 1.1.2.1/24
  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1/112
  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:1/112
local0 (dn):
loop0 (up):
  L3 1.1.1.1/32 ip4 table-id 7 fib-idx 1
```

how to find the expected value ?

Comment: If all after L3 should start with a digit and end with `/` and 1+ digits, which is a broad match, you could use `\G` and the regex PyPi module `(?:host-vpp1out.*|\G(?!^))\n\s+L3\s+(\d[\d.:\/a-z]*)\/\d+`  https://regex101.com/r/GSFUSl/1

Comment: Are you reading this from a file? Is `out` file contents?

Comment: out is like new line separated with \n
eg : 
VirtualFuncEthernet0/7/0.2001 (up):\n  L3 1.1.2.2/24 ip4 table-id 8 fib-idx 2\n  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:2/112 ip6 table-id 8 fib-idx 1\nVirtualFuncEthernet0/9/0 (dn):\nhost-vpp1out (up):\n  L3 1.1.1.1/24\n  L3 1.1.2.1/24\n  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1/112\n  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:1/112\nlocal0 (dn):\nloop0 (up):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and the `\G` anchor and a capturing group which which will be returned by using regex.findall.

```
(?:host-vpp1out .*|\G(?!^))\n\s+L3\s+(\d[\d.:\/a-z]+)\/\d+
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `host-vpp1out.*` Match host-vpp1out and the rest of the line
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\n\s+` Match a newline and 1+ whitespace chars
- `L3\s+` Match `L3` and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d[\d.:\/a-z]*` Match a digit followed by 1+ times any for the listed
- `)` Close group 1
- `\/\d+` Match `/` and 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UvAGDX/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##fZHNTgIxFIXXzlPUWbUg/Rsi2ISwUjes3Vg1Ax2kSW2bmTsGje8@FpQIguYkTdPcc/OdnvgGq@CLrrMvMdSA6uq5WmdZLAGq2k/qHE/VKjQweI1RhBZo70Pf4un5IyHa66Y/K9KBtbnXhirNysH7Q49opk0/z6Bq4KmBGk0Qzu9sDW3pblq/uIZV2l0BZyPGqeRcINxGorTPs7McoVmBBBVUUsnkENk4RFDOXTWwBo3R0s7TZY3k3vRmhTLzseJKbCWVZELI5L085RVf3pNIV4wjbPyOZj/7ScqkRHmE/uvxiDBpQ/h/iL0RFxalOyBzIUT@J1IhDz9u9BM@J6nf2nrA27Lp0npTOoe/O79Au94I6bpP)

**Note** that this part `(\d[\d.:\/a-z]+)\/\d+` is a broad match to match an [ipv4](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html) or [ipv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses) pattern. The links contain pages with a more specific pattern.

Example code

```
import regex

pattern=r"(?:host-vpp1out.*|\G(?!^))\n\s+L3\s+(\d[\d.:\/a-z]*)\/\d+"
test_str = ("VirtualFuncEthernet0/7/0.2001 (up):\n"
    "  L3 1.1.2.2/24 ip4 table-id 8 fib-idx 2\n"
    "  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:2/112 ip6 table-id 8 fib-idx 1\n"
    "VirtualFuncEthernet0/9/0 (dn):\n"
    "host-vpp1out (up):\n"
    "  L3 1.1.1.1/24\n"
    "  L3 1.1.2.1/24\n"
    "  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1/112\n"
    "  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:1/112\n"
    "local0 (dn):\n"
    "loop0 (up):\n"
    "  L3 1.1.1.1/32 ip4 table-id 7 fib-idx 1")

print(regex.findall(pattern, test_str))
```

Output

```
['1.1.1.1', '1.1.2.1', '2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1', '2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:1']
```

---

Using re instead of regex, you could also do it in 2 steps, first matching `host-vpp1out` and the L3 lines. Then from that match, you can get the values in group 1 using re.findall.

```
import re
 
regex=r"^host-vpp1out .*(?:\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*L3 .*)*"
test_str = ("VirtualFuncEthernet0/7/0.2001 (up):\n"
            "  L3 1.1.2.2/24 ip4 table-id 8 fib-idx 2\n"
            "  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:2/112 ip6 table-id 8 fib-idx 1\n"
            "VirtualFuncEthernet0/9/0 (dn):\n"
            "host-vpp1out (up):\n"
            "  L3 1.1.1.1/24\n"
            "  L3 1.1.2.1/24\n"
            "  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1/112\n"
            "  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:1/112\n"
            "local0 (dn):\n"
            "loop0 (up):\n"
            "  L3 1.1.1.1/32 ip4 table-id 7 fib-idx 1")
 
match = re.search(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
 
if match:
    print(re.findall(r" L3 (\d[\d.:\/a-z]+)\/\d+", match.group()))
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/i0oGYw)

Comment: getting this error : error: bad escape \G at position 18

Comment: I can't use regex, its server restriction... any workaround...

Comment: @Rajendra You could also use `re` instead of `regex` and do it in 2 steps https://ideone.com/i0oGYw Did you try Wiktor's solution?

Comment: thanks it worked... will check Wiktor's solution as well....

Answer (score 1):

You may read a file up to the line that starts with `host-vpp1out (up):`, then read all lines below it starting with `"  L3 "`, and save the substrings between the fifth char and `/` using

```
text = """VirtualFuncEthernet0/7/0.2001 (up):
  L3 1.1.2.2/24 ip4 table-id 8 fib-idx 2
  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:2/112 ip6 table-id 8 fib-idx 1
VirtualFuncEthernet0/9/0 (dn):
host-vpp1out (up):
  L3 1.1.1.1/24
  L3 1.1.2.1/24
  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1/112
  L3 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:1/112
local0 (dn):
loop0 (up):
  L3 1.1.1.1/32 ip4 table-id 7 fib-idx 1"""

results = []
f = iter(text.splitlines())
for line in f:
    if line.startswith("host-vpp1out (up):"):
        line = next(f)
        while line.startswith("  L3 "):
            results.append(line[5:].split("/")[0])
            line = next(f)
        break
    
print(results)
# => ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.2.1', '2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1', '2001:db8:0:1:1:1:2:1']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9mh1MY)