# Linux Grep or Sed Regular Expression for IP and optional CIDR

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, ipv4

Wondering if someone might know a easy way to grep both the IP and IP in CIDR form in one go

**Expected Output:**

78.0.0.0/8

136.144.199.198

**Current Output:**

78.0.0.0

136.144.199.198

This is my current regex:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\/[0-9]\{1,\}'
```

This looked like it could work but seems to be only for perl

```
^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))?$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression that matches valid IPv6 addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses)

Comment: @Riaan : You can turn on Perl style regexp with `-P`.

Comment: @user1934428 that looks like a plain old ERE to me which all greps support with `-E`, no need to use `-P` and make it experimental and GNU-specific.

Comment: @EdMorton : I agree that we don't need `-P` here. I mentioned it because the OP expressed familiarity with Perl-Regexp in his question, so I thought he might prefer `-P` over `-E`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three ways:

Use `-P` option for perl regex:

```
grep -Po '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(/[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]|[0-9])?' file
```

Same regex works fine also with `-E` option:

```
grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(/[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]|[0-9])?' file
```

Or escape all special characters:

```
grep -o '\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\(\/[1-2][0-9]\|3[0-2]\|[0-9]\)\?' file
```

All these commands give the same result:

```
78.0.0.0/8
136.144.199.198
```

Comment: That looks like a plain old ERE to me which all greps support with `-E`, no need to use `-P` and make it experimental and GNU-specific.

Comment: @EdMorton: You're right, edited accordingly. I'm using *too much* Perl ;)

Comment: The single digit match should be pushed to the end of the three-part OR expression for the mask value since as it currently is, the match will end at the first digit found and not eg match 1.2.3.4/32, at least with GNU grep 3.7 in it's entirety and quit after seeing the 3

Comment: @Rondo: Good catch, updated accordingly.