# Java Integer.parseInt() Not Working for Large Numbers

Tags: java, class, integer, static-methods, parseint

I have the following simple piece of code which is intended to detect that a given IPv4 address indeed only has numeric values (that is after the dots have been stripped):

```
import edu.gcc.processing.exceptions.net.IPAddressNumericException;

//Get the IP address
  String address = "239.255.255.255";

//Check to see if this is a number      
  try {
    String IPNumbers = address.replace(".", "");
    Integer.parseInt(IPNumbers);            
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
  }
```

For some reason, the `NumberFormatException` is fired, and I get this error:

```
For input string: "239255255255"
```

Could someone please help me understand this? The `parseInt()` method works on smaller numbers, such as `127001`.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, "what is the range of an integer"? (And why might I have asked that question? :-)

Comment: You might want to look into using a regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146/what-are-the-java-regular-expressions-for-matching-ipv4-and-ipv6-strings

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try using `Long.parseLong(IPNumbers)`

Answer (score 7):

Why not use a regular expression, or break it down into its components by using `split(".")`?

There are other limitations besides needing to consist solely of digits. For example:

```
666.666.666.666
```

This will parse just fine, but is an... unlikely IP.

Breaking it up into its parts lets you determine (a) that it has four parts, and (b) that each part actually makes sense in the context of an IP address.

You could also use an `InetAddress` implementation, or [`InetAddressValidator` from Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html).

Comment: Also - a very unfortunate one :)

Comment: +1 for actually suggesting that the approach of just checking whether it is a number is insufficient, and that switching to a long will not solve this

Answer (score 5):

For very large integers you may want to use the [**BigInteger**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class (*or **[BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)**)*, as the values may exceed the limits of Integer.

**Integer Limits:**

```
Minimum : -2147483648
Maximum :  2147483647
```

**Using BigInteger:**

```
string s = "239255255255";
BigInteger yourNumber = new BigInteger(s);
```

Comment: hmm... What method can I use to convert the string to an integer?

Comment: There is also a BigDecimal class if you need one, I'll include the necessary documentation in an edit.

Comment: 239255255255 is not an integer. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE

Comment: @spryno724, An integer will be unable to hold that large of a value, you will have to use BigInteger to store it.

Answer (score 3):

239255255255 is too big to be held by an Integer.  Try using a BigInteger or a BigDecimal.

Answer (score 3):

Range of an `Integer` is **-2,147,483,648** to **2,147,483,647**, the number you have above mentioned is not included in these range, so use `long` , the range of `long` primitive type is in between **-9,223,372,036,854,775,808** and **9,223,372,036,854,775,807**.

So for your case its better to use `Long.parseLong()` function to convert such large number to `long` type.

Answer (score 1):

The logical step up from an integer is a [long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)