# How come InetAddress.getByName("1.2") is valid ip address?

Tags: java

```
public class InetAddresTest {
    public static void main(String ... agrs) {
        try {
            InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName("1.2");
            System.out.println("Good ip address");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

BTW the InetAddress produced ip address comes back as "1.0.0.2" . I could not find a reasonable answer from the javadoc of InetAddress. Can you someone explain this behaviour ?

Comment: Brian is spot on with his answer. If your goal is to validate IP address then I recommend you use Apache-Commons [InetAddressValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html)

Comment: @CoolBeans - added that to the answer, with an alternative as well -  thanks.

Comment: The Apache Commons InetAddressValidator can help only if you're validating IPv4 only, as the current release (1.4) doesn't seem to support IPv6.

Answer (score 8):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html#format)  (Linked in "Textual representation of IP addresses" in the [Javadoc for InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) ):

> When a two part address is supplied, the last part is interpreted as a 24-bit quantity and placed in the right most three bytes of the network address. This makes the two part address format convenient for specifying Class A network addresses as net.host.

**Edit to add:** In case the 24bit part is confusing to you:

`2` in 24bit would look like: `00000000 00000000 00000010`

Which is then mapped to the right 3 octets in the IPv4 address as: `.0.0.2`

**One More:** As CoolBeans mentions in the comments to your question, the [InetAddressValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html) from Apache commons would do the trick. That being said, if you just want to validate IP addresses and not have an external dependency, you can use [Regular Expressions to check IP addresses as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146/what-are-the-java-regular-expressions-for-matching-ipv4-and-ipv6-strings)