# Occasional error Using InetAddress.getByName()

Tags: java, android, inetaddress

In my application, I use InetAddress.getByName() quite a bit to convert strings like "192.168.1.56" to InetAddress objects -- mainly because it seems to me to be a good idea to store IP addresses as IP addresses rather than as strings.  Up til now, I would have sworn it was pretty foolproof too, but today I discovered a bug.  This does not work:

```
InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName ("192.168.1.056");
```

It would appear that my Android thinks THAT string is a host name, and so it's trying to look it up (which isn't possible, because it's not on a "real" network).  Is this something I can work around -- meaning is there a way to insist to getByName that this is an IP address, not a hostname?  Or do I need to build method to purge leading zeroes out of IP address strings??  Or is there an Apache utility buried somewhere that might do a better job of this??

Comment: What's the error you get? Additionally, some implementations will handle leading zeros as an octal value, which won't be what you want. Not sure about this one.

Comment: Check this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556978/how-come-inetaddress-getbyname1-2-is-valid-ip-address

Comment: The error I'm getting is NetworkOnMainThread -- which leads me to believe the software is treating the string as a hostname and going out the network to try to resolve it -- which is both impossible and not the right thing to do.  Sorry about the incomplete post.

Comment: Anas:  I did, but that doesn't seem to be germane to this issue.  My address string has 4 numbers in it, and is separately verified to actually BE and IP address (using a java.util.regex.Pattern).

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that a Regex-wizard could have found a way to fix the IP address string directly, but I don't know how to do that.  However, there is something called the Apache SubnetUtils library which is native to Android.  SubnetUtils doesn't have a cow over an IP address string with a leading zero in it.  My code looks like this:

```
public static InetAddress addrFromStr (String addr)
{
    InetAddress ia = null;
    SubnetUtils su = new SubnetUtils (addr + "/8");

    try
    {
        ia = InetAddress.getByName (su.getInfo().getAddress());
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    { }

    return ia;
}
```

Basically, I create a SubnetUtils object and then ask it for the IP address -- which is now stripped of any numerical strangeness that InetAddress.getByName() apparently can't handle.  (The "/8" business is the CIDR notation subnet mask, and the only thing I can say about it is don't use "/0").

Answer (score 0):

Why not try [getByAddress (byte[] ipAddress)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByAddress(byte[]))? This method seems more suitable for your needs.

Comment: I'm using my code to parse an IP address string provided by the user in a Dialog EditText.  Apparently, one of my users found a new and interesting way to screw things up.  I'm trying to trap the error without resorting to toasting an Invalid Address Error and doing nothing.