# Java code to decompress an IPv6 address

Tags: java, ipv6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the Java regular expressions for matching IPv4 and IPv6 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146/what-are-the-java-regular-expressions-for-matching-ipv4-and-ipv6-strings)

Does anyone have a java code to decompress a given IPv6 address.

I am finding it really difficult to write a regular expression.

Comment: could you show the code you have/ effort you have made?

Comment: so you want regular expression for ipv6 addr?

Answer (score 3):

One of these should help you:

```
public static final String IPV6_HEX4DECCOMPRESSED_REGEX = "\\A((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}(?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})*)?) ::((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:)*)(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)){3}\\z";
public static final String IPV6_6HEX4DEC_REGEX = "\\A((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6,6})(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)){3}\\z";
public static final String IPV6_HEXCOMPRESSED_REGEX = "\\A((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}(?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})*)?)::((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}(?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})*)?)\\z";
public static final String IPV6_REGEX = "\\A(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\\z";
```

Also have a look at [Inet6Address class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html) which will make your life easier.

**Reference:**

- [What are the Java regular expressions for matching IPv4 and IPv6 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146/what-are-the-java-regular-expressions-for-matching-ipv4-and-ipv6-strings)

Comment: David, i did some searching on net and i found a few regular expression. Frankly i am not very comfortable writing regex, for that reason i am looking for a java code.

Comment: @user1601302 have you had a look at the Inet6Address Class link at the bottom of my answer?

Comment: Yes David, i saw it. I want to know if i use the Inet6Address class, will thr be a DNS lookup. My situation is user is keying an Address, i need to validate and decompress it.

Answer (score 0):

Why use regex when you can use [`Inet6Address.getHostAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html#getHostAddress%28%29)?

```
final String compressed = "1080::8:800:200c:417a";
final String decompressed = "1080:0:0:0:8:800:200c:417a";
try {
  final Inet6Address addr = (Inet6Address) InetAddress.getByName(compressed);
  assert addr.getHostAddress().equals(decompressed);
} catch (UnknownHostException ex) { }
```

Comment: Veer, If i try to print the addr.getHostAddress(), it does not print me the canonical form. Is thr a way i can get the Canonical form.

Comment: @user1601302 you can do it with some string manipulation.

Comment: yes, i thought so... :)...And i hope that using InetAddress does not do a DNS lookup..

Comment: @user1601302 if it's a textual representation of the address it will not need to do a DNS lookup.

Comment: The full decompressed format is `1080:0000:0000:0000:0008:0800:200c:417a`, not `1080:0:0:0:8:800:200c:417a`.

Comment: @scai Is there any library to achieve this in Java?

Comment: @GaganTK Unfortunately I'm not aware of any, but I'm only sporadically around in the Java world.