# How to extract a pattern of string(like IP addresses) from another string in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have a string that contains the receive part of an email header. It's like `from abc.xyz.com (abc.xyz.com. [112.35.4.152]) by xx.yy.com with ESMTPS`.

**How can I extract `112.35.4.152` from this string?**

Comment: well the simple case would be to use indexOf and substring for `[` and `]`

Comment: to be honest, this question has shown little or no effort.

Comment: to be honest, wombat, I'm really lost. I've tried every possible way to do this. The problem is, IP addresses do not necessarily contain [ and ].

Comment: "_I've tried every possible way to do this_" If you have tried **every possible way** then what makes you think we can do something different.

Comment: Don't play on words takendarkk. I just wanted to say I did all I could do(at least I think so), that's it. Is stackoverflow some kind of place where newbies aren't welcome at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [RegExp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) approach with [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

```
String str = "from abc.xyz.com (abc.xyz.com. [112.35.4.152]) by xx.yy.com with ESMTPS id ...";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
} else {
    System.out.println("No match.");
}
```

Prints:

> 112.35.4.152

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.indexOf("")` to locate your `[` and `]` indexes, supply those index values to `String.substring()` method , and extract the substring.

```
String Str="from abc.xyz.com (abc.xyz.com. [112.35.4.152]) by xx.yy.com with ESMTPS id";
System.out.println(Str.substring((Str.indexOf("[")+1), Str.indexOf("]")) );
```

Edit:- Please be more specific in your questions, I read in your comments that the ip address being enclosed in `[]` is not guranteed , in that case you need to use regex.

the pattern for IPV4 ip addresses is

```
\\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146/what-are-the-java-regular-expressions-for-matching-ipv4-and-ipv6-strings) (Also you can find regex for IPV6 here)

Here is a small snippet that should work for you:-

```
 String ip_pattern ="\\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b";
 String input="from abc.xyz.com [112.35.4.152](abc.xyz.com. by xx.yy.com with ESMTPS id ";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ip_pattern);
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

 if (matcher.find()) {
     System.out.println(matcher.group());
  }
 else{
     System.out.println("No ip found in given input");
  }
```

Comment: What comment ? please be more specific.

Comment: Thank you Mustafa. I couldn't upvote your answer because I have low reputation, but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @joiner It is in reference to the person who downvoted my answer, If you did not downvote, it is not meant for you.

Comment: Ok, I deleted my comments. Delete yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
"from abc.xyz.com (abc.xyz.com. [112.35.4.152]) by xx.yy.com with ESMTPS id ...".
```

By looking at your `String`, you can just get a substring start after `[` and end with `]`

```
String s = "from abc.xyz.com (abc.xyz.com. [112.35.4.152]) by xx
                                                    .yy.com with ESMTPS id ...";
int startIndex=s.indexOf("[");
int endIndex=s.indexOf("]");
System.out.println(s.substring(startIndex+1,endIndex));
```

Output:

```
112.35.4.152
```

Read about [String#substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String IPADDRESS_PATTERN = 
    "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ipString);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group();
    }
    else{
        return "0.0.0.0";
    }
```

`Credits:` [Extract ip address from string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875013/extract-ip-addresses-from-strings-using-regex)

Comment: you literally copy pasted the answer.....assume i did -1, ohh wait...some1 did it already!!

Comment: I thought a simpler `\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b` would work